# Finding Derivatives of Functions

Tags: derivatives

I've recently been reading a text on classical mechanics and the Mathematics applied to the use of Derivatives and second derivatives, and I was hoping some folks could verify my answers to the following questions:

[A] Calculate the derivatives of each of these functions:

$f(t) = t^4 + 3t^3 - 12t^2 + t - 6$

$g(x) = \sin x - \cos x$

$\theta(\alpha) = e^\alpha + \alpha\ln\alpha$

$x(t) = \sin^2 x - \cos x$

[B] The derivative of a derivative $\frac{d^2f(t)}{dt^2}$ is the second derivative. Find the second derivative of each of the functions listed above:

Any answers or method used will be of much help. Thanks!

Comment: 'I was hoping some folks could verify my answers to the following questions' Where are your answers ?

Comment: On a piece of of paper I wrote down, I just wanted to see what other people would put so that I could review and analyse my mistakes (if any).

Comment: Then I suggest you write out the answers you do have :). Then we will correct where need be.

Comment: Well, could you share it with us? These derivatives are not that long to write down, even without LateX. We will help...

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x)=4t^3+9t^2-24t+1$

$g'(x)=\cos(x)+\sin(x)$

$\theta'(x)=e^x+\ln(a)+1$

$x'(t)=\sin(2t)+\sin(t)$ (I believe you meant $x(t)=\sin^2(t)-\cos(t)$)

---

$f''(x)=12t^2+18t-24$

$g''(x)=\cos(x)-\sin(x)=g(x)$

$\theta''(x)=e^x+\frac{1}a$

$x''(t)=2\cos(2t)+\cos(t)$